# Convert sql to view in stored procedure then return limited rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I need to compare two tables and then filter out only those records that do not have a matching record.
I then need to return only a few of those rows.
To return rows I use...

```sql
SELECT  *
    FROM     (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orderby ASC)
                 AS Row, * FROM vImportFiltered where userid <> @userID)
                AS vImport
    WHERE  Row >= @NumbFrom AND Row <= @NumbTo
```

For the filter of records I use...

SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ImportProducts IP Where IP.ImpProdNameID = @impProdNameID and IP.ImpProdCatID = @ImpProdCatID and

```sql
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *

           FROM   dbo.ProductDetails PD INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductsLU PL ON PD.LUProdSellUseID = PL.LUProdSellUseID
        WHERE
           IP.ImpProductID = PD.ProdImpID AND
           (CONVERT(varchar(36),PL.UserID) = @userID))
```

Both work separately but when I try to combine them I get errors.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
  (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orderby ASC)
                 AS Row, * ImportProducts IP Where IP.ImpProdNameID = @impProdNameID and IP.ImpProdCatID = @ImpProdCatID 
and    
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *

           FROM   dbo.ProductDetails PD INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ProductsLU PL ON PD.LUProdSellUseID = PL.LUProdSellUseID
        WHERE
           IP.ImpProductID = PD.ProdImpID AND
           (CONVERT(varchar(36),PL.UserID) = @userID)) as vImport
WHERE  Row >= @NumbFrom AND Row <= @NumbTo
```

Errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 
Incorrect syntax near 'ImportProducts'. 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

I've also tried

```sql
WHERE
           IP.ImpProductID = PD.ProdImpID AND
           (CONVERT(varchar(36),PL.UserID) = @userID))And Row >= @NumbFrom AND Row <= @NumbTo
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that you forgot `from` here: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orderby ASC) AS Row, * FROM ImportProducts IP`

Comment: You do, but after the asterisk one would expect from.

Comment: Above, the 3rd grayed area from the top, I do have the select row_number etc.  It just doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly. Find the word `ImportProducts` and prepend `FROM` there.

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure what you suggest?  BTW thanks for your help

Comment: You are missing a keyword FROM after the asterisk and before ImportProducts - unless the code you provided is not complete.

Comment: Haven't used stackoverflow.  I am trying to figure out how to send you the code.  It has Save Edits... Not sure

Comment: Sheri, check @bluefeet's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `FROM`

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orderby ASC) AS Row, * 
    FROM ImportProducts IP -- added your missing FROM
    Where IP.ImpProdNameID = @impProdNameID 
    and IP.ImpProdCatID = @ImpProdCatID 
    and    
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM   dbo.ProductDetails PD 
                  INNER JOIN dbo.ProductsLU PL 
                    ON PD.LUProdSellUseID = PL.LUProdSellUseID
                  WHERE IP.ImpProductID = PD.ProdImpID 
                    AND (CONVERT(varchar(36),PL.UserID) = @userID)
                  )
  ) as vImport
WHERE  Row >= @NumbFrom 
    AND Row <= @NumbTo
```

Comment: Actually closing bracket is missing - alias is for derived table.

Comment: I now receive the error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: It works!  I made a typo.  Thank you very much for your help.